# How to extract all ID variables from a query string?

Tags: query

What is the best php method to extract all IDs from a query string and display them in a comma separated list?

I have a function that grabs specific posts from the database and am trying to enter those ID's into a new wp_query loop.

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [ID] => 162
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2011-10-22 09:25:46
        [post_date_gmt] => 2011-10-22 14:25:46
        [post_content] =>
        [post_title] => Paper III
        [post_excerpt] =>
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => open
        [ping_status] => open
        [post_password] =>
        [post_name] => paper-iii
        [to_ping] =>
        [pinged] =>
        [post_modified] => 2011-12-22 09:22:05
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2011-12-22 14:22:05
        [post_content_filtered] =>
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http:/mysite.org/?post_type=album&p=162
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => album
        [post_mime_type] =>
        [comment_count] => 0
        [user_nicename] => matt
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [ID] => 166
        [post_author] => 2
        [post_date] => 2011-12-22 11:32:46
        [post_date_gmt] => 2011-12-22 16:32:46
        [post_content] =>
        [post_title] => mtayla's album
        [post_excerpt] =>
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => open
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] =>
        [post_name] => mtaylas-album
        [to_ping] =>
        [pinged] =>
        [post_modified] => 2011-12-26 20:23:00
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2011-12-27 01:23:00
        [post_content_filtered] =>
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http:/mysite.org/?post_type=album&p=166
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => album
        [post_mime_type] =>
        [comment_count] => 0
        [user_nicename] => mtayla
    )
    [2] => stdClass Object (
        [ID] => 308
        [post_author] => 2
        [post_date] => 2012-01-31 15:04:29
        [post_date_gmt] => 2012-01-31 20:04:29
        [post_content] =>
        [post_title] => another album
        [post_excerpt] =>
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => open
        [ping_status] => open
        [post_password] =>
        [post_name] => another-album
        [to_ping] =>
        [pinged] =>
        [post_modified] => 2012-01-31 15:04:29
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2012-01-31 20:04:29
        [post_content_filtered] =>
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http:/mysite.org/?post_type=album&p=308
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => album
        [post_mime_type] =>
        [comment_count] => 0
        [user_nicename] => mtayla 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$string` will contain a comma separated list of IDs:

```
$ids = array();
foreach( $array as $post ) {
    if( !in_array( $post->ID, $ids ) ) {
        $ids[] = $post->ID;
    }
}

$string = implode( ', ', $ids );
```

Note: This uses basically no wordpress, other than the post object...which is really just an object.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a WordPress question, but you could just use `array_map` to extract the IDs, but them in an array and `implode` that...

```
$id_array = array_map('my_id_extraction', $rows);
function my_id_extraction($item){
    return $item->ID;
}
$id_list = implode(',', $id_array)
```

Comment: So in your example $rows is the full array? I know that it is more php, but I posted it here because I thought it was applicable for others trying to extract info from wpdb.

Comment: Yup, `$rows` is the full array. I've not tested the above but it should work.