# How to make WP_Query 'post__in' accept an array?

Tags: wp-query

I have [a function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41175/how-to-extract-all-id-variables-from-a-query-string) that returns a comma separated list of post ids that a particular user can access. I want to use this list in a WP_Query loop.

The custom function:

```
$array = user_albums();
foreach( $array as $post ) {
    if( !in_array( $post->ID, $array ) )
        $ids[] = $post->ID;
}
$access_ids = implode( ', ', $ids );
```

So here is the situation:

1. On my test site the id list is `158, 162, 145, 269`.
2. Inserting the list of ids returns only the first post. `'post__in'=> array(
   $access_ids ),`
3. Inserting the list of ids not in an array returns an error. `'post__in'=>     $access_ids ,`
4. Inserting the post ids manually returns correct
   posts `'post__in'=> array( 158, 162, 145, 269 ),`

**What could I be doing wrong?**
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Thanks guys for the input! The implode array was indeed causing the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$access_ids` is a string. `post__in` accepts an array.

So instead of $access_ids you could use `'post__in'=> $ids` skipping the `$access_ids = implode( ', ', $ids );` all together.

Comment: for me this also not work can you please help me?

Answer (score 7):

That `implode()` is probably what breaks things:

```
$access_ids = '158, 162, 145, 269';

$array = array($access_ids); //wrong
var_dump( $array ); 
// array
//  0 => string '158, 162, 145, 269' (length=18)

$array = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $access_ids ) ); // right
var_dump( $array ); 
//array
//  0 => string '158' (length=3)
//  1 => string '162' (length=3)
//  2 => string '145' (length=3)
//  3 => string '269' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set `'post__in'=>$ids`, declaring array( $access_ids ) doesn't create the desired array.