# get_posts by id not working

Tags: get-posts, id

I have the following code:

```
global $post;
$current_post = $post->ID;
$array=range(1,$current_post);
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=5&post__in=' . $array . '&category='. $category->term_id . '&exclude=' . $current_post);
```

The error appeared is `Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/todaytra/public_html/depmua/wp-includes/query.php on line 2159`

Could any one point out the mistake with my $array valiable?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Where are you defining `$current_post`?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @imHavoc It works perfectly without the second argument, meaning that the $current_post variable is correctly defined

Comment: What is the value being returned by `$current_post`?

Comment: When i `echo $current_post` it gives `213629` . Without the `post__in` argument i get nicely 5 posts, some have id larger than 213629, some smaller. By the way, i don't have too much posts (i deleted a lot of post revisions and drafts, that's why i have that big ID)

Answer (score 1):

I have just found an alternative solution:

```
global $post;
$current_post = $post->ID;
$array=range(1,$current_post);
$args = array(
'numberposts'     => 5,
'offset'          => 0,
'category'        => $category->term_id,
'orderby'         => 'ID',
'order'           => 'DESC',
'exclude'         => $current_post,
'post_type'       => 'post',
'post_status'     => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true,
'post__in' => $array );

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

I'm not sure why the previous method does not work. I have resolved the problem anyway. Thank @imHavoc and @userabuser for having taken a look at my problem :)

Comment: That's because you're not passing an array of values into `get_posts` in your OP. The syntax you described above is the correct syntax. [See this thread](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41390/how-to-make-wp-query-post-in-accept-an-array) for further understanding.

Comment: also you can use get_the_id function i think instead of $post->ID.

[link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)

Comment: array is a PHP keyword, I would advise you choose a different name for your variable

Comment: @pamapple please check the tick mark on the left to the answer to mark your answer accepted.